# Darwin Streaming Server 6.0.3 not running in web console after installation

Tags: video-streaming, ubuntu-12.04, darwin

after following perfectly this procedure to install Darwin Streaming Server 6.0.3

http://list-archives.org/2012/12/13/streaming-server-users-lists-apple-com/install-darwin-streaming-server-on-ubuntu/f/5640560927

I get

```
Server is Not Running
The server is currently not running.
Please start it before attempting to administer it.
```

on the browser, when I try to call the URL :1220.

Also if it helps: I don't have any /usr/local/sbin/DarwinStreamingServer or /etc/streaming/streamingserver.xml files after installation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to install it on Ubuntu  10.04 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

:~# sudo apt-get install gcc g++ build-essential

:~# cd usr/local/src

:~# sudo wget https://www.linux-bd.com/linux/darwin-server-6.0.3.tar.gz

:~#  tar zxvf darwin-server-6.0.3.tar.gz

:~# cd darwin-server-6.0.3

:~# tar xvf DarwinStreamingSrvr6.0.3-Source.tar

:~# sudo addgroup --system qtss

:~# sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --ingroup qtss qtss

:~#   tar -xvf DarwinStreamingSrvr6.0.3-Source.tar

look up the full command  to patch :~# patch -p0    [dss-6.0.3.patch]

look up the full cammand to patch :~# patch -p0    [dss-hh-20080728-1.patch]

:~# cd DarwinStreamingSrvr6.0.3-Source

:~# rm Install

:~# cp -r /usr/local/src/darwin-server-6.0.3/Install ./

:~# chmod +x Install

:~# cp -r /usr/local/src/darwin-server-6.0.3/Makefile.POSIX ./

:~# sudo ./Buildit

:~# sudo ./Install

:~#  cp -r /usr/local/src/darwin-server-6.0.3/darwin-streaming-server /etc/init.d/darwin-streaming-server

:~#  chmod +x  /etc/init.d/darwin-streaming-server

:~#  cp -r /usr/local/src/darwin-server-6.0.3/streamingserver.xml /etc/streaming/

:~#   /etc/init.d/darwin-streaming-server restart